# VB6 Index of Substring

Tags: string, vb6

I'm trying to match domain names in email address strings in VB6 and it's not my everyday language. I basically want to extract the domain name from an address (i.e., admin@foo.com) for comparison. I would like to extract it by getting everything after "@" and I think finding the index of "@" and then using `Left$()` would satisfy my needs. How can I get the index?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `InStr` function to do this:

Example:

```
s$ = "admin@foo.com"
d$ = Mid$(s$, InStr(1, s$, "@") + 1)
```

The variable d$ would end up with the string "foo.com".  (Don't forget to check to make sure that the @ sign is present, otherwise you would just end up with the whole source string.)

Comment: Since I should check for the @, I'll use InStr() to determine that, but what value does it return if "@" is not a substring of the address string?

Comment: The function will return a 0 if the string is not found.

Comment: +1 See the VB6 manual topic on Instr http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445031(v=VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `Split` function here.

```
Dim strEmail, arr, strDomain
strEmail = "emailaddress@website.com"
arr = Split(strEmail, "@")
if arr.Count > 1 then
    strDomain = arr(1)
end if
```

Hope this helps.

Edit
Sorry forgot to add a check that the array has more than 1 value.

Comment: These variables should really be strongly typed instead of defaulting to Variants.  More importantly though arrays don't have a Count property.  Aside from that this would be a workable solution.

Comment: A couple of other points: (1) `Split` returns a zero-based array, so you'd need to use `arr(0)` to access the first array element; (2) a usable (albeit clumsy) replacement for the non-working `arr.Count` is to use `UBound(arr)-LBound(arr)+1`.