# how to find a string on a string in vb 6.0

Tags: string, search, vb6

hi i have this problem finding a string on a text box
so far this what i have it only detect the comma char, now i i input 23pm,24,25am how will i do this with this code or anybody can give me the simple code?

```
Dim tdates() As String
Dim numberOfDates, xcount As Integer
tdates = Split(TXTDAYS.Text, ",")
numberOfDates = UBound(tdates)
Dim counter As Integer

' loop through each input
For counter = 0 To numberOfDates
    Dim xdate As String
    xdate = LCase$(tdates(counter))

If Len(xdate) <= 2 Then
  xcount = xcount + 1
  Else
        ' if the original text has am or pm in it, add .5
        If InStr(1, xdate, "am") > 0 Or InStr(1, xdate, "pm") > 0 Then
            xcount = xcount + 0.5 'problem here it doesn't count
        End If
    End If
Next
```

if there is a better way to do this by detecting the comma and the am pm string much better.

Comment: i revise this code i been searching and this is i come up.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly this function is trying to accomplish?

Comment: im trying to detect the am and pm in the textbox with the whole number, the whole number is equivalent to 1 and the am and pm is 0.5, i think the is wrong with this code the searching for whole number is correct but when i put the am or pm the computation is incorrect, like the example above 23pm,24,25pm the 23am=0.5, 24=1 and 25pm=0.5

Comment: If a number does not have am or pm, does it get counted as 1?  Also, what happens if there are other non-numeric values ("23q, 24, 25am")?

Comment: if doesn't have pm or am equivalent to 1, and if there is other non-numeric values thats the other problem, but now i want to focus on calculating the date, although if you can help me by that, it would be great sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Split`](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb-string-array-functions-split-join-filter) the text on comma.  Then your array will have all of the whole words in it

Use [`InStr`](http://www.aivosto.com/vbtips/instr.html) to search for am or pm.

[`Replace`](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/vb6-string-functions) AM and PM with "" and check the remainder of the text for a number (for validating)

```
' split the input on a comma.
dim dates() as String = Split(TXTDAYS.Text, ",")
dim numberOfDates as Integer = UBound(dates)
dim counter as Integer

' loop through each input
For counter = 0 to numberOfDates
    dim dateEntered as String = LCase$(dates(counter))

    ' make sure the text entered is a number (once am and pm are removed)
    dim dateNumber as String =  Replace(Replace(dateEntered, "pm", ""), "am", "")
    if IsNumeric(dateNumber) Then
        COUNT = COUNT + 1

        ' if the original text has am or pm in it, add .5
        if Instr(1, dateEntered , "am") > 0 Or Instr(1, dateEntered , "pm") > 0 Then
            COUNT = COUNT + .5
        end if
    else
        ' do something to indicate invalid input
    end if 
Next
```

Comment: i modify the code but some of them id dont get or i cant convert to vb "dateNumber = tdate.Replace("am", "").Replace("pm", "")" = object required

Comment: sir where can i put my new code? i have modify the code seems there is a little problem about counting the .5

Comment: i dont know whats wrong with this the xcount doesn't add it self  xcount= xcount + .5 return 0 but if xcount= xcount +1 return 1

Comment: You have xcount defined as an integer.  Integers are whole numbers.  You have to use a floating point variable (Single or Double).

Answer (score 0):

using instr()..

```
s = "admin@foo.com"
d = Mid(s, InStr(1, s, "@") + 1)
```

The variable d$ would end up with the string "foo.com". (Don't forget to check to make sure that the @ sign is present, otherwise you would just end up with the whole source string.)

taken from this post..

[VB6 Index of Substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935658/vb6-index-of-substring)

Thanks!

@leo

Comment: if im goin to check the am and pm i will just change the "@" to "am"/"pm". im using a loop to count every detection of "," also i want to detect the am and pm at the same time would it be posible?